# Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=132001 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

When I upgrade to iOS 13, a bunch of things in my app seem to have broken. One of them is how my data is saved. When I hit the save button I get this unresolved error:

```
    Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=132001 "(null)" UserInfo={message=attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted, stack trace=(
    0   CoreData                            0x00007fff23759236 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 170
    1   owed                                0x000000010f86f76a $s4owed13CoreDataStackC11saveContextyyF + 186
    2   owed                                0x000000010f8d8347 $s4owed14ViewControllerC05tableB0_12cellForRowAtSo07UITableB4CellCSo0iB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF + 10215
    3   owed                                0x000000010f8d8cb5 $s4owed14ViewControllerC05tableB0_12cellForRowAtSo07UITableB4CellCSo0iB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTo + 165
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47360e4b -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 787
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47361364 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 73
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4738ea9c -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells] + 7750
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4739805f -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 118
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4732efb0 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 2883
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47326f5f -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 17188
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47340d22 -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 112
    11  owed                                0x000000010f8db9fb $s4owed14ViewControllerC26controllerDidChangeContentyySo016NSFetchedResultsC0CySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pGF + 267
    12  owed                                0x000000010f8dba64 $s4owed14ViewControllerC26controllerDidChangeContentyySo016NSFetchedResultsC0CySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pGFTo + 68
    13  CoreData                            0x00007fff238e00be __82-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 7591
    14  CoreData                            0x00007fff2376ebfb developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 154
    15  CoreData                            0x00007fff2376eae2 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 197
    16  CoreData                            0x00007fff238de305 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 105
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac2c1c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac20a5 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 421
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac1e0f ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 175
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bbffe3 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1811
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac1776 _CFXNotificationPost + 950
    22  Foundation                          0x00007fff2564d429 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 59
    23  CoreData                            0x00007fff2375b4fe -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 541
    24  CoreData                            0x00007fff237feb3a -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:wasMerge:] + 1557
    25  CoreData                            0x00007fff23755ff3 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 1217
    26  CoreData                            0x00007fff237592fb -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 367
    27  owed                                0x000000010f86f76a $s4owed13CoreDataStackC11saveContextyyF + 186
    28  owed                                0x000000010f955d53 $s4owed23AddPersonViewControllerC8saveNameyyypF + 11699
    29  owed                                0x000000010f956360 $s4owed23AddPersonViewControllerC8saveNameyyypFTo + 80
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47163d19 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46b55599 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46b558e3 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 398
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46b54842 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 481
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4719e21f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2604
    35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4719fb26 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4596
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4717b1a7 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    37  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471faa18 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 6847
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471fd4de __handleEventQueueInternal + 5980
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afbac1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afb9ec __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afb1c4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af5ecf __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af56b6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    44  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff3815cbb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    45  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47162a67 UIApplicationMain + 1621
    46  owed                                0x000000010f8fe4db main + 75
    47  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5123bcf5 start + 1
)}, ["stack trace": <_NSCallStackArray 0x600000e5d560>(
0   CoreData                            0x00007fff23759236 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 170,
1   owed                                0x000000010f86f76a $s4owed13CoreDataStackC11saveContextyyF + 186,
2   owed                                0x000000010f8d8347 $s4owed14ViewControllerC05tableB0_12cellForRowAtSo07UITableB4CellCSo0iB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF + 10215,
3   owed                                0x000000010f8d8cb5 $s4owed14ViewControllerC05tableB0_12cellForRowAtSo07UITableB4CellCSo0iB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTo + 165,
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47360e4b -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 787,
5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47361364 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 73,
6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4738ea9c -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells] + 7750,
7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4739805f -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 118,
8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4732efb0 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 2883,
9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47326f5f -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 17188,
10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47340d22 -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 112,
11  owed                                0x000000010f8db9fb $s4owed14ViewControllerC26controllerDidChangeContentyySo016NSFetchedResultsC0CySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pGF + 267,
12  owed                                0x000000010f8dba64 $s4owed14ViewControllerC26controllerDidChangeContentyySo016NSFetchedResultsC0CySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pGFTo + 68,
13  CoreData                            0x00007fff238e00be __82-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 7591,
14  CoreData                            0x00007fff2376ebfb developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 154,
15  CoreData                            0x00007fff2376eae2 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 197,
16  CoreData                            0x00007fff238de305 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 105,
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac2c1c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12,
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac20a5 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 421,
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac1e0f ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 175,
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bbffe3 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1811,
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac1776 _CFXNotificationPost + 950,
22  Foundation                          0x00007fff2564d429 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 59,
23  CoreData                            0x00007fff2375b4fe -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 541,
24  CoreData                            0x00007fff237feb3a -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:wasMerge:] + 1557,
25  CoreData                            0x00007fff23755ff3 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 1217,
26  CoreData                            0x00007fff237592fb -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 367,
27  owed                                0x000000010f86f76a $s4owed13CoreDataStackC11saveContextyyF + 186,
28  owed                                0x000000010f955d53 $s4owed23AddPersonViewControllerC8saveNameyyypF + 11699,
29  owed                                0x000000010f956360 $s4owed23AddPersonViewControllerC8saveNameyyypFTo + 80,
30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47163d19 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83,
31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46b55599 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223,
32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46b558e3 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 398,
33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46b54842 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 481,
34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4719e21f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2604,
35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4719fb26 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4596,
36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4717b1a7 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356,
37  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471faa18 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 6847,
38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471fd4de __handleEventQueueInternal + 5980,
39  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afbac1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17,
40  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afb9ec __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76,
41  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23afb1c4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180,
42  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af5ecf __CFRunLoopRun + 1263,
43  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23af56b6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438,
44  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff3815cbb0 GSEventRunModal + 65,
45  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47162a67 UIApplicationMain + 1621,
46  owed                                0x000000010f8fe4db main + 75,
47  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5123bcf5 start + 1
)
, "message": attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted]
```

This is the save function:

```c
 /* =====================================
     Save Function
     ======================================*/
    @IBAction func saveName(_ sender: Any) {

        /* STEP 1 - Check to see if there is a person name in the input field */
        guard name.text! != "", name.text! != "Add Name" else {
            // call the warning function
            warningText = "You forgot to add a name."
            warningMessage()
            return
        }

        /* STEP 2 - Check to see if that persons names was already used */
        let personFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
        personFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name.text!)

        print(name.text!)

        do{
            let results = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(personFetchRequest)
            print("\(results.count)  this is the results count for the predicate")
            guard results.count == 0 else{
                // print("The Same Name is Used")
                warningText = "You already used that name."
                warningMessage()
                return
            }

            /* STEP 3 - Use the name that was typed in */
            let person = Person(entity: Person.entity(), insertInto: coreDataStack.managedContext)
            let trimmedName = name.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            person.name = trimmedName

            if(email.text! == "" || email.text! == "Email Address"){
                person.email = "Email Address"
            }else{
               person.email = email.text
            }

            if(mobile.text == "" || mobile.text == "Mobile Number"){
                person.mobile = "Mobile Number"
            }
            else{
                person.mobile = mobile.text
            }

            person.dateCreated = NSDate() as Date
            person.priority = 9999

            /* STEP 4 - Save the data */
            coreDataStack.saveContext()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});

        }catch{
            print("Error")
        }

        self.dissmissViewController(cancelBtn!)
    }
```

When I close the app, and open it agian, the correct data displays. I'm not really sure what the error is saying for me to figure out where to begin to research an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tough to see exactly what's happening without more code, but it seems to be telling you that you're recursively saving the context (i.e for some reason the act of saving the context causes the context to be saved, which causes the context to be saved, which causes the context to be saved....etc)

From the call stack it appears that something like this is happening:

1. You save the context
2. The `FetchedResultsController` you're using gets a notification that something changed.
3. Your `UITableView` gets updated with the new data
4. The act of displaying the new cell somehow triggers the context to be saved again. **This is where the problem is - this shouldn't be happening.**
5. The `FetchedResultsController` you're using you're using gets a notification that something changed.
6. Steps 3-5 repeat forever

I'd put break points wherever `coreDataStack.saveContext()` is called, run the app and try and see why it's getting recursively called when cells are displayed after a save.